# mvn process-resources doesn't pull down uber jar created with shade plugin

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, executable-jar, maven-shade-plugin

Goal: Create an executable uber jar with maven shade plugin that can be executed during the mvn compile of another pom.

**Repro steps:**

1. Create a pom.xml for the "publisher" component using below pom.
2. Use a Jenkins build to mvn deploy it (mvn install will work as well)
3. Add dependency to pom.xml for "consumer" (pom below)
4. mvn compile the consumer

**Expected behavior:**
Uber jar for publisher is downloaded somewhere in consumer/target directories

**Actual:**
Uber jar does not appear in consumer directory

**Component 1: Publisher**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.mec.experiment</groupId>
<artifactId>publisher</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.6.Final</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifestFile>src/main/resources/META-INF/MANIFEST.mf</manifestFile>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

**Component 2: Consumer**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.mec.experiment</groupId>
<artifactId>consumer</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mec.experiment</groupId>
        <artifactId>publisher</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: Where did you specify that the publisher has a classifier? You're using `<classifier>publisher</classifier>` in the dependency of the consumer.

Comment: Ah, vestigial from a previous experiment. I tried with both the poms above and with 

publisher:
<configuration>
    <shadedArtifactAttached>true</shadedArtifactAttached>
    <shadedClassifierName>publisher</shadedClassifierName>
</configuration>

consumer:
<classifier>publisher</classifier>

Same behavior in both cases. 

Updated the consumer pom to remove the classifier for internal consistency.

Comment: Okay. What do you mean by "target directories" here? I'm not sure I understand why the publisher should be downloaded "somewhere in consumer/target directories".

Comment: Maybe I'm dealing with a basic misunderstanding on my part. I expected that including a dependency to consumer would automatically download the jar somewhere. The analogy in my mind was having a dependency that's automatically included in a classpath for the javac command, and having that persisted onto the filesystem somewhere during the process-resources phases.

Comment: Included in the classpath, yes. And it will be downloaded into your local repository under `~/.m2/repository`. But the processs resources phases, or the target folder don't come in play here. Maven will download the dependency right at the start of the build.

Comment: In looking at mvn compile -X in another project, I see that dependency jar download only appears to happen during mvn compile. So something learned!

In consumer, I do see compile errors related to not finding publisher.jar in the compile path. So I guess I don't fully understand how maven pulls dependencies into the compile path (or somewhere else) to successfully compile code that relies on dependencies. Once I have the publisher jar somewhere i can access it as part of mvn steps in consumer, I'm golden.

Comment: I tried to start writing something longer than a comment, but really there's not too much more to explain than what @Tunaki said. Your `~/.m2/repository` becomes the holder of all your jar files - dependencies and your own maven builds. You have access to your publisher.jar therein - for me, I see: `[INFO] Installing /home/jsampson/dev/workspaces/neon-1a-stackoverflow/publisher/target/publisher-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar to /home/jsampson/.m2/repository/com/mec/experiment/publisher/1.0-SNAPSHOT/publisher-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar` Do you think you want another shaded uber jar for consumer in the end?

Comment: @JonSampson: So is the recommendation to reference the jar from its location in the m2 repo? E.g., java -jar ${M2_HOME}/repository/com/mec/experiment/publisher/1.0-SNAPSHOT/publisher-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar? I can do that, but I'm just surprised if that ends up being the recommended way.

Comment: Can you expand on what you want to do with producer and consumer?

Comment: @JonSampson: Publisher produces a self-contained, executable jar. In our case, the jar publishes test results to a centralized location. Consumer wants to call that jar as part of its mvn verify step to publish its test results.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Invoke a jar file in the M2 repository](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9833707/invoke-a-jar-file-in-the-m2-repository)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [answer from the possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9833935/6768037) I linked to in the comments has a link to a dead example page. Here's a [supplement](http://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/java-mojo.html) for you. The plugin configuration would belong inside the consumer pom.

> exec:java
>
> Full name:
>
> org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.5.0:java
>
> Description:
> Executes the supplied java class in the current VM with the enclosing project's dependencies as classpath.
>
> Attributes:
>
> Requires a Maven project to be executed.
> Requires dependency resolution of artifacts in scope: test.
> The goal is thread-safe and supports parallel builds.
> Since version: 1.0.

See especially `executableDependency` for your use case. That looks like it will allow you to reference `producer` according to its group id and artifact instead of hard-coding a path.